# Get Variable From Another Class Form Dialog MFC/C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I meet a problem about getting variable between two dialog
I tried to build simple project below:

**DemoAppMFCDlg.h**

```
class CDemoAppMFCDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CDemoAppMFCDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    void FillDataToArray();
public:
    CStringArray* arrData;
// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_DEMOAPPMFC_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
...
};
```

**DemoAppMFCDlg.cpp**

```
BOOL CDemoAppMFCDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    FillDataToArray();
    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CDemoAppMFCDlg::FillDataToArray()
{
    arrData = new CStringArray();
    arrData->Add(L"A");
    arrData->Add(L"B");
    arrData->Add(L"C");
    arrData->Add(L"D");

}
```

Now `DemoAppMFCDlg` is showing, if I click OK button on it, `DialogChild` will show.
Here is code of `DialogChild`:

**DialogChild.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Resource.h"
// DialogChild dialog

class DialogChild : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(DialogChild)

public:
    DialogChild(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~DialogChild();

    void GetDataDemoAppMFC();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG_CHILD };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

**DialogChild.cpp**

```
// DialogChild.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DemoAppMFC.h"
#include "DemoAppMFCDlg.h"
#include "DialogChild.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// DialogChild dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(DialogChild, CDialog)

DialogChild::DialogChild(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(DialogChild::IDD, pParent)
{
    GetDataDemoAppMFC();
}

void DialogChild::GetDataDemoAppMFC()
{
    **CDemoAppMFCDlg *cdemo = new CDemoAppMFCDlg();
    CStringArray* getData = cdemo->arrData;**
}
DialogChild::~DialogChild()
{
}

void DialogChild::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(DialogChild, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// DialogChild message handlers
```

As you know see, afer initializing `CDemoAppMFCDlg`, I filled data to `arrData` by calling `FillDataToArray()` function, afer initialising `DialogChild`, `GetDataDemoAppMFC()` function is called to get value of `arrData`.

I know I should put `arrData` in the `private` mode however I also try putting it on `public` mode to access directly but value of it return `NULL`.

Comment: It can be a lot simpler. Just declare a `CStringArray*` variable in `DialogChild`, with public access . In `CDemoAppMFCDlg`, after calliing the `DialogChild` constructor and before the `DoModal()` call, set this variable to be equal to the `CDemoAppMFCDlg`'s one: `childDlg.arrData = arrData`. No casting needed and the `DialogChild` class code doesn't need to include _DemoAppMFCDlg.h_ - the opposite isn't true, as `CDemoAppMFCDlg` has to call the `DialogChild` constructor anyway. You should NOT call the `CDemoAppMFCDlg` constructor, it's the main app window and you don't want another instance.

Answer (score 3):

WINAPI comes with a lot of dark magic (low level operations). MFC, along with MSVC wizards do their best to hide those to the programmer but you still have to respect one major rule: use MFC classes as they are intended to be used. I urge you to follow Microsoft (MSDN) tutorials for you first MFC applications: you will not truely understand how and why but they should work.

Here your immediate problem is that you initialize data in `CDemoAppMFCDlg::OnInitDialog`. Which is called via the framework when the underlying (WINAPI) window is initialized. But as you only create an instance of the MFC class, this initialization never occurs. You must be aware that the MFC classes are intended to be use as wrappers around the underlying WINAPI objects, the reason why you should only create them through their special methods.

Here you should *not* create a new `CDemoAppMFCDlg` but (assuming it is the main window) use `AfxGetMainWnd` to get a pointer to the existing instance:

```
void DialogChild::GetDataDemoAppMFC()
{
    CDemoAppMFCDlg *cdemo = STATIC_DOWNCAST(CDemoAppMFCDlf, AfxGetMainWnd());
    CStringArray* getData = cdemo->arrData;**
}
```

---

Above solution only makes sense if the main window of the application is a CDialog instance. For the generic use case (SDI or MDI application using a `ChildView`) a simple way if just to pass the creator CWnd when creating the `DialogChild`:

```
INT_PTR cr = DialogChild(this).DoModal();
```

You can then directly use the *parent* in the constructor or just save it there to use it later:

```
DialogChild::DialogChild(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(DialogChild::IDD, pParent)
{
    CDemoAppMFCDlg *cdemo = STATIC_CAST(pParent, CDemoAppMFCDlg);
    CStringArray* getData = cdemo->arrData;
    // Now use or save getData
    // Beware: the Dialog window is not constructed at that time
    //   so it can make sense to just save getData into a member
    //   and use it later in OnInitDialog
}
```

Comment: Hi Serge Ballesta, It's working. Thanks for your answer. I'm appreciated that

Comment: Please do not forget to accept the answer to notify others that you no longer need help with this question.

Comment: Hi Serge Ballesta, I found that in case if I create a dialog CDemoAppMFCDlg that is inherited CPropertyPage not CDiaglog, the program will show a message box "debug assertion failed" after calling STATIC_DOWNCAST(CDemoAppMFCDlg, AfxGetMainWnd());

Comment: @LinhNH_TB: `AfxGetMainWnd()` returns (a pointer to) the top level window of the application. It is fine for a top level dialog, but not for more complex hierachies where the *interesting* window is not the top level one. Property pages is a good not working example... I'll try to give a different path in a while.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative (if appropriate) is to make the `CStringArray` in the child dialog as a **reference**. Then you pass the `CStringArray` by reference in your child's constructor.

Now it has read / write access to the array and there is no need to make it public.

Another solution is to use `SendMessage` or maybe `PostMessage` to send a message to the parent to return a pointer to the array object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I posted in my comment. It's a simple solution, based on C++ only, not using MFC or WinAPI, and probably the one that needs the least code to implement: just pass the data to the child dialog.

**DialogChild.h**

```
class DialogChild : public CDialog
{
    .
    .
public:
    // pointer to the data, set and managed by the caller
    CStringArray* arrData
    .
    .
};
```

**DialogChild.cpp**

```
//#include "DemoAppMFCDlg.h" - No need to #include "DemoAppMFCDlg.h" here
```

**DemoAppMFCDlg.cpp**

Create and display the child dialog.

```
    DialogChild childDlg(this); // or maybe pass another window, or nothing - pls check the MFC documentattion
    childDlg.arrdata = arrdata; // sets the child's arrdata pointer, doesn't create and/or copy the array.
    if (childDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        .
        .
    }
    else
    {
        .
        .
    }
```

It can be even simpler though. As the `CDemoAppMFCDlg` class is instantiated only once (a "singleton") so does the `arrdata` array. Therefore it wouldn't make much of a difference if it was created and declared as a global variable (although I know some may disagree here)